# Techniques for understanding Android Methods

Tags: java, android, oop

I have just finished up my first book on Java training and I think I am getting closer to understanding.  I am currently looking for some good resources to improve my java understanding.
So far I have read through http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-tutorial/ however I am still not clear.

what is the best way to find out all the possible methods that relate to an Android Object.  Is there something in eclipse which can make it clear?

Please can you point me in the right direction? and giveing an example that a beginner would understand would be wonderful and much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess the best way to find any method or class is to look in the Android API which can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

And this is the Java API which works the same way:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

You can search for classes and find which methods and properties they have.

You should have direct access to the API from the Eclipse code completion: http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?fromSeriesID=6&name=IntroductionToEclipseWithJava2_JohnM

I would also reccomend WiBit.net for more tutorials on both Java and Android if you are a beginner. They have some awesome free material:
http://www.wibit.net/curriculum/courses/programming_java

TheNewBoston also have some nice tutorials on android where you can pick up more although they are not as good as the WiBit ones:
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL34F010EEF9D45FB8

Comment: Those are great resources, but how for example do I see that Listview has the method GetlistView(): Its not listed in the reference on the Android Developer Docs.  Where would I be able to find that info?

Comment: getListView() is part of the ListActivity class, I agree they can be hard to find sometimes. Or am I missing your point? :P

Comment: Thanks- it only really became clear when I started looking at more Java methods, then when I came back to Android, its clear that I just need to look at the public methods for the main objects. In case someone else is looking for where to find getlistview---> its under List activity public methods- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html. Thanks for the help and guiding path! :)